# what is the voltage at the emitter of optocoupler 4N25?

Tags: opto-isolator

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHWBqz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am using the emitter voltage to drive another transistor. But voltage is zero.

Comment: Did you really connect 5V directly to the input diode?  If so, you've ruined the part.

Comment: This cannot be answered unless we know the current flowing through D1. Do you know the current flowing through D1?

Comment: I am using new one, this time it is 4n35, and current through d1 is approx. 8mA

Comment: Not the problem here, but you should connect a resistor from base to emitter (maybe 56K) to avoid humidity causing a partial turn-on of your opto. Refer to my answer in [why mosfet is getting very hot?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/73041/why-mosfet-is-getting-very-hot/73066#73066) for more details.

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting Vo from the transistor it is driving?

Comment: @bharaththink, please update your schematic to show how you are really driving the LED.

Answer (score 5):

4N25 and quite a few other opto devices have what is known as "current transfer ratio". For the 4N25 this is specified as being greater than 20%.

This means if you stuff 20mA into the diode, you should expect to see at least 4mA through the opto-transistor and your emitter resistor is 1k so you should see something like 4V or possibly a little greater.

If you are putting 10mA into it don't expect much above 2V on the emitter.

[image]

This is the table from the data sheet - note that there testing conditions are with collector-emitter voltage at 10V.

If you are not registering any voltage at the emitter, the diode could be broken - try measuring its volt drop after the resistor in series with it. Alternatively you may have connected it up incorrectly. Also check your 1k emitter resistor isn't  something like 1 ohm and check your collector is at 5v.

Answer (score 0):

If you implemented this very schematic, then your opto-isolator need to be replaced, because the LED inside is already burned.

And before switching ON the schematic next time, put a current limiting resistor in series with the input.